# MacOS autopause video when conference is active

Tags: google-chrome, video, firefox

On MacOS chrome and firefox (although quicktime) both have strange behavior - when you are on call (zoom/discord/etc) if you try tyo start video in browser it pauses after some seconds. Time before pause is not stable - may be half a second may be 10 seconds.

Although videos that was paused that way simultaneously starts when conference is over.

Could not find anything in google except one post in allpe discussions without answers.
Weired things...

MacOS Sonoma but on BigSur it was the same.

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: how to disable this behavior?